# Python: Passing Variable to Range()

Tags: python-3.x, excel-2007, xlwings

Hi and thank you in advance.

Using Python 3.4 in Visual Studio 2015, to read/write from Excel 2007

Looking to pass a variable:

```
mylastrow ='$A$70006' # this address is not hard coded. it will be from an 'input'
```

Joining the above Range to the expression below is what i am failing at:

```
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' & lastrow).value
```

I have tried these:

```
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' & lastrow)
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' + lastrow).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' + lastrow)
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' & str(lastrow)).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' & int(lastrow)).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' + str(lastrow)).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:' + int(lastrow)).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2', 'A' & lastrow).value
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2', 'A' & lastrow).value
```

I keep getting: 'unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int''
or 'Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly'

Of course, after they are together, the address should look like A2:$A$70006

Even if you just have a link to a list of possible workarounds or just "this can't be done". Anything will well. Thank you again.

ps. For the forum itself, if i should have presented this in another way or should have structured this another way, please let me know so that I can fix it. thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mylastrow ='$A$70006'
...
myrange = xlwings.Range('Sheet1', 'A2:{0}'.format(mylastrow)).value
```

More about [python 3 string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) can be read from here.

Comment: Hi Ance. This worked. I thank you and am going to go find out about how  format() works so that I can get the most out of it in the future. Thank you. Ps. I was trying: Range('Sheet1','A2:%s' % lastrow), and Range('Sheet1','A2:A %d' % lastrow), where 'lastrow' = 70006, but nothing was working. Thank you so much.

Comment: That % string formatting might also work if You use it like Range('Sheet1','A2:%s' % str(mylastrow)).value, but then you have to take care of passing the correct type of parameter (number, string, ...). That str.format() is more like python 3 way to do that. Anyway, no problem and i'm glad to help You :)

Comment: @Jim you might want to use xlwngs' ability to address cell indices rather than addresses, e.g.: `Range((1,1),(10,10))`